# What does "bound to github" mean?

Tags: neovim

The lastest Vim documentation has this paragraph:

> **Neovim** A Vim clone. Forked the Vim source in 2014 and went a different way.
> Very much bound to github and has many more dependencies, making
> development more complex and limiting portability. Code has been
> refactored, resulting in patches not being exchangeable with Vim.
> Supports a remote GUI and integration with scripting languages.

What does "bound to github" mean? Bound in what way?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, the phrase seem to have been added in 2019 with [4c05fa08c](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/4c05fa08c9739e307ddc88ac91ba6d208f1fd68e#diff-644ad027e3580bc940a6b7b4aaf1869bae267f7ff30e359e523d5de70e317106R291-R296). I think this is mostly Braam's opinion but the best place to have a real answer is probably asking in [vim user support mailing list](https://www.vim.org/maillist.php)

Comment: That being said, I believe it's a reference to how Neovim's entire ecosystem is substantially more GitHub-centric, where as Vim isn't. Off the top of my head, there's mailing lists, a mercurial repo (that, now, is a mirror of the GitHub repo), and other stuff that's not exclusively on GitHub. I'm not sure about all the details, though, because the project is a decade older than I am, so I don't know what systems there used to be, and by extension, what was preserved. It's not really a matter of opinion, though - it's an objective observation, and one that's trivial to prove (or disprove)

Comment: Whether it's an advantage or a disadvantage, though, is intentionally left out of the text, because _that_ is a matter of opinion. You might prefer it, dislike it, or not care as long as you get to clone, install, and move on to something more interesting.

Comment: Actually, I think it might be a reference to how contributed patches are managed in Vim. In all cases, they make it into Vim as a commit with Bram as the author (Bram is the original author of Vim), not with the author of the patch as the owner of the commit... I think the NeoVim folks talked about it in a presentation, talking about how Vim was still centralized on Bram himself, and NeoVim would break away from that model depending on a central person. I'll try to find that video to post in an answer, I think that makes sense here...

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys, so you do not think that "bound to github" refer to functionality in any way, just to the development process?

Comment: @filbranden It seems Bram has changed the way he handles commits from other authors around the end of April 2021. At the time I write this the [Vim contributor page](https://github.com/vim/vim/graphs/contributors) at github lists 20 additional contributors and the commits in the respository show them as the author of the respective patch and Bram as the committer.

Comment: Ah, a nice and welcome change! But pretty recent too, for the longest time it wasn't so. Note that the workflow is not "bound to GitHub" since it's not done by merging PRs. There's a reason for that, in that commits make it into numbered patch versions of Vim which need to be assigned sequentially, but still it means there's a centralized model in which development doesn't progress unless the single author/owner/maintainer is on top of it.